# Automatically update a mongo document after expiration date using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically update a certain document after an expiration date. Let's say I have this schema in mongoose

```
const clientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
        //login email and password
        email           : { type: String, unique: true },
        password        : String,
        dateCreated     : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        status          : { type: String, default: 'Active'}
    }
});
```

Let's say, if a client was created today (June 22, 2017) is it possible to change the status to Inactive after July 22, 2017??

I know mongo has TTL settings but it deletes the whole document. **Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a cron job (node-cron) which goes through the database once everyday to remove it, simplest way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the cron job. although I don't want to remove the document to my database but I'll try it and see what it can do. Thanks mate.

Comment: If you don't want to remove the document then add a field say flag and set it's flag to false. When retrieving data from the db only retrieve those with true value. If that was helpful please upvote it.

Comment: I did upvote but I don't have reputation. Thanks mate.